# Where is key binding for Ubuntu Desktop help?

Tags: shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My audio <kbd>mute</kbd> button has recently stopped working. The <kbd>volume down</kbd> button now starts the Ubuntu Desktop Help window. The <kbd>volume up</kbd> button works just fine. The <kbd>mute</kbd> and <kbd>volume down</kbd> buttons work fine for the other user on the box.

I explored `Dconf` and the two keys should work - but they don't!

I used `xbindkeys -k` in both users and got the same results.

---

Problem solved! All my keys are working properly after I removed "Keytouch."

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Danibix. I checked System Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Sound and Media and the key bindings are correct. That's the part that has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try from `System Settings`, select `Keyboard` and then go the `Shortcuts` tab. From there you can check which keys are bound to *Sound and Media* actions.

If there is some mismatch you can set the right key.